# Unknown module(s) in Qt: networkauth

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am getting this error when trying to compile one C++ Qt project

```
Unknown module(s) in QT: networkauth
```

The *.pro file starts with:

```
QT += core gui network networkauth
```

It's Fedora 31 KDE, I did install qt5-qtnetworkauth and qt5-devel,
I am reading that it could be due to wrong LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but none of the changes I was trying to resolved my problem. Qt version is 5.14.1

Can someone suggest where the problem may be?

Thank you

Comment: Did you include the Qt Network Authorization component when you installed Qt? You can use the maintenance tool to check.

Comment: I resolved it by removing qt completely and installing it again - not very beautiful solution, but I was tired already and, most importantly, it resolved my problem

Comment: For future reference, you can use the maintenance tool to add (or remove) components, in this case the Qt NA component you needed. Much faster than doing a complete reinstall.